# Successful Login to API; Unsuccessful at accessing any data due to being unauthorized

Tags: api, google-apps-script, cookies, urlfetch

I am attempting to come up with a live leaderboard for my local club using the PDGA's (Professional Disc Golf Association) API. I am writing a Google Apps Script intending to auto populate a Google Sheet with a Club Ranking that can be refreshed as needed.

Right now, all I am trying to do is make pull of data to ensure I am able to begin using the API, but I can't seem to do even that.

For reference, here are the only two resources I have to work with regarding this specific API:

[PDGA REST API Authentication](https://www.pdga.com/dev/api/rest/v1/auth)

[PDGA REST API Services](https://www.pdga.com/dev/api/rest/v1/services)

I have got the original login to work using this code:

```
function apiLogin() {
  var LoginUrl = 'https://api.pdga.com/services/json/user/login';
  var LoginDetails = {
    'username' : Username,
    'password' : Password
  };
  var LoginRequest = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : LoginDetails
  };

  var LoginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(LoginUrl, LoginRequest);
  var json = LoginResponse.getContentText();
  var LoginData = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(LoginData);
  var SessionID = LoginData['sessid'];
  var SessionName = LoginData['session_name'];
  var Tok = LoginData['token'];

  var playerFetchPar = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'Cookie' : SessionID + '=' + SessionName
  };
  var PlayerResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pdga.com/services/json/players?pdga_number=1',playerFetchPar); //ERROR
  Logger.log(PlayerResponse);
};
```

It's the last part when I am trying to call on data from a player that I get the following error message:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.pdga.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: ["Access denied for user anonymous"] (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I am guessing that my screw up is in my interpretion of the parameter `Cookie` from that second link. In the initial response to make sure I was logging in properly, I received a `session_name` and `sessid` but I can't seem to figure out what is expected from `Cookie`. I am sorry if the answer is obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.pdga.com/dev/api/rest/v1/services#player-search) says

> Cookie: session_name=sessid

You've used

> ```
> Cookie: sessid=session_name
> ```

Reverse it:

```
'Cookie' : `${SessionName}=${SessionID}`
```

And you need to send it as a [header](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en#fetchurl,-params):

```
const playerFetchPar = {
    method : 'get',
    headers: {'Cookie' : `${SessionName}=${SessionID}`}
};
```